# Downloading grails-1.1.1

Tags: grails

I am trying to download grails-1.1.1 from https://grails.org/downloads. But looks like  I don't have access to http://dist.codehaus.org/grails/grails-bin-1.1.1.zip. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it from https://grails.org/dist/grails-bin-1.1.1.zip.

Be aware that 1.1.1 is very old and has long not been supported.

Comment: Not there anymore

Comment: @karthi4all You can now find it at https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases/tag/v1.1.1.

Comment: Thanks. this works.